Are the O-rings at the ends of faucet supply hoses replaceable?
The pressure-seal in the faucet supply line is slowly leaking. I guess, it is just the rubber O-ring, but I'm not sure, whether it is removable...
The washer resists my needle-nose pliers and I don't want to try too hard for fear of damaging it. The garden hoses are attached with the same mechanism -- and the O-rings there are supposed to be changed every year. But on this one, it seems a lot harder to do...
Are these supposed to be replaceable at all, or is one expected to replace the entire hose, when a leak develops?

Can you add a picture of you valve, hose, and the washer?   JACK's answer feels right to me.  Most supply hoses are compression fittings.  A common problem is the use of thread tape that prevents the joint from tightening enough, or properly, to seal the way it should.  Another problem is a leak NEAR the fitting, blamed on the fitting, leading to the use of thread tape after which there are two leaks, indiscernible from one another.

the last few hoses using 3/8 compression nut (w/ embedded o-ring as seal ) I had to mess with employed o-ring Veri-near measured at 1/2" OD x 3/8" ID , of square cross section, of various THICKNESS from 1/8" & up.
The nuts having been zealously tightened, so the orings fairly chewed up
Replacing the connector hose isn't always an answer (for instance , faucets with permanent hoses crimped at the valve side) and the IMHO the oring is all thats often needed.
The orange box store was little help, so I Aced it to look through the various buna orings. Didn't find that 1/2x3/8 ring in round or square section, but my local orings in various OD; 12mm (too small) 14 (kind of big) and deeper in back a few 13mm (goldilocks!) in various cross sections from 1.5~3mm.
The 13mm OD fits best in the gland nut, but they lacked any 3mm X-section in that OD.
I did just order off ebay some 13mm OD x 3mm section silicone (softer than buna)  rings for about a nickel per , here in a mere 3 weeks. Ready next time !
Thats when I realized I also had a large pack of orings, (available for power washer hose gasket replacements) which had the 13mm x3mm in a lovely soft soylent green.
connections not leaking yet.
OK - flipping the chewed oring over to use the fresh face on the seal was a possibility too, for you True Scotsmen.
Reading back over the years , I'd say thread tape is more miss than hit, the threads on these compression connections are NOT pipe, (not tapered), not designed for a interference fit, so the tape probably isn't very reliable.
The straight thread also means the oring THICKNESS is not as critical as the height of the outgoing o ring might indicate, as long as there is some crush on the ring. Check the fitting's sealing faces for nicks, too. Flatter is better.
Digging the old oring out may cost you a jewler's screwdriver if you reef too hard on it but it isn't bonded, so it will come out with some coaxing.

Do you have the same answer for multiple questions?

Garden hoses endure sunlight, freezing, dirt and grime getting into the fittings.  So they tend to fail. Failure is not catastrophic, you just have a leak in the garden.  They are not normally under pressure except when in use so a new leak is usually observed immediately. So patching things up is a good economical strategy.  You can just keep fixing a hose with $2 parts until there's barely one molecule of the original hose left.
Indoors on the other hand, supply hoses should last years, decades.  They are always under pressure, usually out of sight and never handled, so a new problem might not be observed for a long time.  So, at the first sign of any problem I would replace a supply hose, including possibly the fittings it attaches to if the problem is at the interface. A big indoor leak is catastrophic, and performing maintenance on a part that isn't meant to be maintained rather than just replacing it for $10 is the wrong approach.

I know, I already ordered a replacement. It just pains me, that we're ready to discard an otherwise functional device, because a minor component of it failed. (Almost) like replacing a car, because the ashtray is full :-)

You may be unlucky but more likely, either A) something caused it to fail, and you should figure it out before you ruin another one, or B) it was a poor hose and hopefully this time you get a good one and the next failure will be when someone who isn't even born yet owns the house.   Nobody in this forum would feel differently than you on this.  We all like to fix sh*t.  But sometimes fixing means replacing.  It's not like the ashtray is full.  It's like your tire sidewall tore open.  Ya, there's videos on youtube of people patching bits of two tires together into one but come on.

Is it an O-ring or a flat rubber type washer?  O-rings are rubber round solid tubes/rods shape, like hair ties.
O-rings usually need very fine picks to get behind them.
Something like toothpick size.  If it has a hook/bend even better.
Make sure all dirt/rubber pieces are removed/clean out before putting new one in.
They come in different diameters/thickness, so replacing with the same is important for a good seal.

I doubt those are "O"rings in that supply line. They are not plain, flat washers either. They are tapered a bit at the front and protrude a bit into the tube from the nut. They will normally last for many years unless they are over tightened when installed. Funny that the instructions warn not to over tighten but there's nothing to say how tight they should be. I snug it up and they give it another quarter to half turn and check it in a day or two for drips.
Trying to find a replacement washer would be a waste of time. Just buy a new supply line and be done with it.
